# ActiveRecord generated SQL in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working on a project which requires talking to two different databases:  a MySQL one for persistent data and an experimental in-memory database for real-time data.

It would make my life a bit easier if there was a way to access and use the SQL Query generated by the ActiveRecord finders.

---

I know there have been other questions along these lines but the answers they had seemed to suggest logging the SQL to STDOUT and were not for Rails 3

Comment: I don't really understand, does to_sql answers your question?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I tried calling to_sql on Model.all but that seemed to return the result string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Model.all` executes the query and you are trying to call `to_sql` on an Array.

Do this

```
Model.scoped.to_sql
```

Comment: yes, I knew I was doing it wrong.  scoped seems just about what I'm looking for, can it do the full range of queries?

Comment: You can chain scopes and call to_sql in the end. This works with my model User.where("1=1").joins(:user_info).to_sql Produces "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_infos` ON `user_infos`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE (1=1)"